# Series sum in python

Tags: python, numpy

Is there is a built-in function in python, numpy or one of its libraries can get sum of series like this one:

```
list1 = [2,3,4]
list2 = [3,3,3]
```

[image]

where x and y are lists and L is the length of x or y.

Lastly if there is no built-in function do that, I tried another code like :

```
Total = sum ((i for i in list1) * (j for j in list2))
```

Sure, it doesn't work but I need something near that or near this one:

```
Total = sum (i * j for i in list1 and j in list2 )
```

Note : I can build my own function to do that but I am looking for a simple, fast or built-in one, so please don't give me your own function.

Edit : I want general form to do that so I can use this form when there are as an example **`Log(n)` or another kind of math** in the series.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

for build-in you can use [zip](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to group together elements in the same index position

```
list1 = [2,3,4]
list2 = [3,3,3]
result = sum( x*y for x,y in zip(list1, list2) )
```

**About the edit**

A buil-in version would be

```
from math import log
result = sum( log(i)*y for i,y in enumerate(list1,1) )
```

a more generalized version would be

[image]

```
import operator
def dotproduct(vec1, vec2, sum=sum, map=map, mul=operator.mul):
    return sum(map(mul, vec1, vec2))
```

where you can provide whatever function you like for any of its part, then the first one is

```
result = dotproduct(list1,list2)
```

and the second is could be

```
result = dotproduct(range(1,len(list1)+1),list1, mul=lambda i,x:log(i)*x )
#                        ^ the i                    ^ how to operate
```

or

```
result = dotproduct(map(log,range(1,len(list1)+1) ), list1 )
#                           ^ the log i
```

the point being that you calculate the second vector accordingly

with numpy is more easy

```
import numpy as np
logi = np.log(np.arange(1,len(list1)+1)
result = np.dot(logi,list1)
```

which again boils down to calculate the parts accordingly

---

you can also make such that instead of receiving 2 vectors/lists it only work with one and receive a function that work in the element and its index

[image]

```
def sum_serie(vect, fun = lambda i,x:x, i_star=0): #with that fun, is like the regular sum
    return sum( fun(i,x) for i,x in enumerate(vect, i_star) )
```

and use it as

```
result = sum_serie( list1, lambda i,x:log(i)*x, 1)
```

---

from the comments, if I get it right, then something like this

```
from itertools import islice
def sum_serie(vect, *slice_arg, fun = lambda x:x): #with that fun, is like the regular sum
    """sum_serie(vect, [start,]stop[,step], fun = lambda x:x)"""
    if not slice_arg:
        slice_arg = (0,None,None)
    return sum( fun(x) for x in islice(vect, *slice_arg) )
```

or with enumerate as before

```
from itertools import islice
def sum_serie_i(vect, *slice_arg, fun = lambda i,x:x): #with that fun, is like the regular sum
    if not slice_arg:
        slice_arg = (0,None,None)
    return sum( fun(i,x) for i,x in islice(enumerate(vect), *slice_arg) )
```

and use, for example as

```
sum_serie( x, 0, 100, 2, fun=lambda xi: c*xi) #for arbitrary constant c
sum_serie_i( x, 0, 100, 2, fun=lambda i,xi: log(i)*xi)
```

Note: this way it accept the serie/iterable/whatever and at most 3 positional argument with the same meaning as those from range

Note 2: that is for PY3 which make fun a key-word only argument, in python 2 the same effect is accomplished with

```
def sum_serie_i(vect, *slice_arg, **kargv): 
    fun = kargv.get('fun', lambda i,x:x) #with that fun, is like the regular sum
    if not slice_arg:
        slice_arg = (0,None,None)
    return sum( fun(i,x) for i,x in islice(enumerate(vect), *slice_arg) )
```

Comment: @cropperfield: Case one  has a different answer than case 2 .
And so on if i changed the elements inside the series , increase number of them or change the series condition ,i have to adapt with it and make a private solution (function) for it.
For more clarify :
 There is no formula i can give it the elements of series and condition of it as parameters , like :
sum_series(x[n],log(n),n,0,100,2)
where x is a series or whatever , and n is the iterating number and 0 is the initial value of n  ,100 is the final value of n and 2 the increment amount of n every time .

Answer (score 9):

That's literally just a dot product:

```
result = numpy.dot(list1, list2)
```

Note that if you're using NumPy, you shouldn't be using lists to represent your matrices and vectors. NumPy arrays are much more efficient and convenient for that.

Comment: but what if they are not lists inside the series .Let the series contains log(n)  ,can we apply your solution or any another one to do it .
Is there is  a general form to do series sum ?!

Comment: @mohammedawni: Unclear what you're asking. What do you mean by "contains log(n)", and how are you imagining this series would be represented? In general, you can perform sums with `numpy.sum` for arrays or the built-in `sum` for iterables, as long as you can represent your series as an array or iterable.

Answer (score 1):

The mathematical operators with numpy arrays do element-wise operations, so you can use:

```
import numpy as np
np.sum(np.multiply(list1, list2))
# or np.sum(list1 * list2)  if any of list1/list2 is a numpy array
```

or in the second case:

```
logi = np.log(np.arange(1, len(x)))  # or np.log10, not sure which one you mean
np.sum(np.multiply(logi, x[1:]))
```

as already mentioned `np.sum(np.multiply())` is just a dotproduct, so you could also use `@` (at least with python 3.5+, otherwise use `np.dot`):

```
np.asarray(list1) @ list2  # if list1/list2 are numpy arrays you don't need the np.asarray
```

Answer (score 1):

These all do the same thing

***[`np.einsum`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html)***

```
np.einsum('i,i', list1, list2)
```

***[`np.inner`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.inner.html)***

```
np.inner(list1, list2)
```

***[`np.dot`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dot.html)***

```
np.dot(list1, list2)
```

All yield `27`

For bigger arrays, `np.einsum` starts to see a performance boost

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use `*` operator and sum it along `0`th axis.

```
In [48]: a
Out[48]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4])

In [49]: b
Out[49]: array([5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [50]: a*b
Out[50]: array([ 0,  6, 14, 24, 36])

In [51]: np.sum(a*b, axis=0)
Out[51]: 80
```

---

But, you should really be using the much cooler and ultra-fast `np.inner()`

```
# `a, b` can also be python lists
In [65]: np.inner(a, b)
Out[65]: 80
```